# If condition with && precedence not working

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
if (!IDTextField.value && !FirstNameField.value && 
     !LastNameField.value && !DateOfBirthField.value!GenderField.value) {
    alert('No criteria Added');
    return;
}
```

The `alert` is not called when all the text fields are blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `&&` between the last two criteria

It should be:

```
if (!IDTextField.value && !FirstNameField.value && 
     !LastNameField.value && !DateOfBirthField.value && !GenderField.value)
```

In cases like this, it makes a lot of sense to format your if statement like this:

```
if (     !IDTextField.value   
      && !FirstNameField.value   
      && !LastNameField.value   
      && !DateOfBirthField.value    
      && !GenderField.value)
```

If you do it this way, you can't make the mistake you just made.

Answer (score 2):

xbonez got it right. You are missing && between last two expression.

For something not so important, I would like to get all expressions evaluated using `||` and then add negation using `!`, rather than negating all expression and evaluate them with `&&`. This can make this expression a little faster, if am not wrong.

```
if (!(IDTextField.value || FirstNameField.value || 
     LastNameField.value || DateOfBirthField.value || GenderField.value)) {
    alert('No criteria Added');
    return;
}
```

Tell me what you all think??

Comment: Totally. Every not (!) is an operator. So !x && !y is effectively 5 operations. against !(x || y)'s 3 operations.

Answer (score 1):

What is this little abomination?

```
... !DateOfBirthField.value!GenderField.value
```

I think that should be:

```
... !DateOfBirthField.value && !GenderField.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your code like this

```
if (!IDTextField.value && !FirstNameField.value && 
     !LastNameField.value && !DateOfBirthField.value && !GenderField.value) {
    alert('No criteria Added');
    return;
}
```

You're missing the && between the last two criteria

Answer (score 1):

the `&&` is missed ,add it and try ,should work if no other errors exist